# How to split a column into two using whitespace

Tags: r

I have the below input data frame. I need to split this df into two columns[l,r] based on white Space between them. The problem is most of the library are not present in compile Env . Is there any other approach without using 'dplyr' or 'tidyr'

**Input**

```
df
    val
1   5 5
2   2 7
3  8 10
4 10 20
5   4 5
```

**Output**

```
df
   l  r
1  5  5
2  2  7
3  8 10
4 10 20
5  4  5
```

Comment: Can you please share the input as `dput(df)`? It's hard to import columns with white space as you've shared them.

Comment: structure(list(val = c("5 5", "2 7", "8 10", "10 20", "4 5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% extract(val, c("l", "r"), "(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)")

   l  r
1  5  5
2  2  7
3  8 10
4 10 20
5  4  5
```

Answer (score 4):

Easier with `base R` by making use of `read.table` to read the column 'val' and it automatically splits up the column at the whitespace.  Just specify the column names (if we need one) or it will create default names.  Advantage is that it will change the automatically instead of manually changing if we use `strsplit`

```
read.table(text = df$val, header = FALSE, col.names = c('l', 'r'))
```

-output

```
 l  r
1  5  5
2  2  7
3  8 10
4 10 20
5  4  5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(val = c("5 5", "2 7", "8 10", "10 20", "4 5")), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R option with `scan`

```
> matrix(scan(text = paste0(df$val)), nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)
Read 10 items
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    8   10
[4,]   10   20
[5,]    4    5
```

or (thank @Onyambu's comment)

```
> list2DF(scan(text = df$val, what = list(as.numeric(), as.numeric())))
Read 5 records
       
1  5  5
2  2  7
3  8 10
4 10 20
5  4  5
```

---

A `data.table` option using `tstrsplit`

```
> setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(val, " ", type.convert = TRUE)]
   V1 V2
1:  5  5
2:  2  7
3:  8 10
4: 10 20
5:  4  5
```

Comment: There is a `type.convert` in case the Op wants as numeric type `setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(val, " ", type.convert = TRUE]`

Comment: @akrun Oh, yes. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: if you are using `scan` include the `what` argument thus you will not need to use as.matrix: `list2DF(scan(text=df$val, what=list(as.numeric(), as.numeric())))`

Answer (score 3):

You may also use `tidyr::separate`

```r
df <- read.table(text = "    val
1   '5 5'
2   '2 7'
3  '8 10'
4 '10 20'
5   '4 5'", header = T)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(val, into = c('l', 'r'), sep = '\\s')
#>    l  r
#> 1  5  5
#> 2  2  7
#> 3  8 10
#> 4 10 20
#> 5  4  5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution with `str_split` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(df$val, " ", 2)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "5"  "5" 
[2,] "2"  "7" 
[3,] "8"  "10"
[4,] "10" "20"
[5,] "4"  "5"
```

data (borrowed from AnilGoyal):

```
df <- read.table(text = "    val
1   '5 5'
2   '2 7'
3  '8 10'
4 '10 20'
5   '4 5'", header = T)
```